# How to deal with multiple queries for each resource?

Tags: c#, graphql, graphql-dotnet

I want to create a GraphQL API with .NET Core using the GraphQL and GraphiQL package. I created one query for users and one for tasks

```
public sealed class UserQuery : ObjectGraphType
{
    private List<User> users = new List<User>();

    public UserQuery()
    {
        Field<ListGraphType<UserType>>(
            "users",
            "Returns a collection of users.",
            resolve: context => users);
    }
}

public sealed class TaskQuery : ObjectGraphType
{
    private List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    public TaskQuery()
    {
        Field<ListGraphType<TaskType>>(
            "tasks",
            "Returns a collection of tasks.",
            resolve: context => tasks);
    }
}
```

I created two schemas to "register" the queries

```
public sealed class UserSchema : GraphQL.Types.Schema
{
    public UserSchema(UserQuery userQuery)
    {
        Query = userQuery;
    }
}

public sealed class TaskSchema : GraphQL.Types.Schema
{
    public TaskSchema(TaskQuery taskQuery)
    {
        Query = taskQuery;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I've seen that this is not possible because I have to register `ISchema` as a singleton service

```
serviceCollection
    .AddSingleton<ISchema, UserSchema>()
    .AddSingleton<ISchema, TaskSchema>();
```

So the `TaskSchema` overwrites the `UserSchema`. One solution would be to have one single schema with one single query containing the content of `UserQuery` and `TaskQuery` but things get messy really fast, no?

Any better ideas to split the resources?

I think things might get very complex when dealing with 100 fields or even more.

Comment: maybe try not to use ISchema serviceCollection.AddSingleton<UserSchema>().AddSingleton<TaskSchema>()

Answer (score 2):

Every GraphQL schema needs to contain exactly one query type: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/

And one endpoint can only surface one schema. <strike>If you want to split it up into multiple files, you could use partial classes.</strike>
You can use partial classes, but you might have to do some reflection magic to distribute the Code from the ctor. One could use reflection to call any method in the class that starts with "Init" for example. Then the partial classes can declare init methods and to what they need

Alternatively, you could also explore hot chocolate, there you do not need to declare a single schema. You can add all the different query types and they are merged automatically.

Comment: would you mind providing a small code example for the partial classes approach? this sounds interesting because currently I have a huge query file with multiple resources and I don't like it ...

Comment: yeah would like to see it too :)

Comment: I tried to create this https://pastebin.com/x1F60Qu2 but obviously I can't use the constructor twice ...

Comment: Sorry, yes it works for everything _except_ for the constructor.